# Benefits of using .NET ORM tools like Entity Framework, LinqToSql over stored procedure

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, entity-framework, stored-procedures, orm

I would like to know the benefits of using .NET ORM tools like Entity Framework, LinqToSql over stored procedure approach for scalable website.

Comment: Over **Store procedures**? That's not a question, as you still use SP in ORM Tools ... God if you don't! It's a must in long queries!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many benefits to using ORM Tools, but they are not a replacement for Stored Procedures.

ORM Tools are a replacement for the manual process of defining and writing data and/or business classes.  It saves the developers time and effort by letting them worry about what data to get instead of how to get the data (amongst other things).

Additionally, stored procedures are usable (and sometimes recommended) alongside ORM Tools.

Comment: Any advice on where NOT to use ORM tools but should consider Stored Procedures?

Comment: Honestly Stored Procedures should be used whenever possible.  They provide you with more flexibility (IE: small changes to SQL without needing to recompile/install/deploy the application).  I find that if I'm making a utility application (something that might only get used twice a year) then I do not bother with making stored procedures though.

Answer (score 0):

ORM tool is not a replacement of stored procedure. It reduce your task to write class that mapped with database and realationship among those class. It also check the validatoin on data you dont need to do manual stuff for this. Stored procedure can also be used with ORM tool alongside.